# Cannot click <circle> on pupeteer

Tags: click, puppeteer

Not able to click a unique  element using puppeteer
I am able to identify an circle element using document.querySelectorAll and it comes out to be unique selector('#output-con-node-0 > circle[class*="flowchart-canvas__outputConnector"][r="5"]').
Click does not happens when try to click it.

I have tried element.click() and mouse.click() but nothing worked for me

I expect the circle element to be clicked as I have its unique selector
but actually, the click is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work to click your element:

`await page.click('#output-con-node-0 > circle[class*="flowchart-canvas__outputConnector"][r="5"]');`